# Switching codec of elementary audio stream in MPEG-2 transport stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, codec, mpeg

I am trying to recreate a bug in a device that receives an mpeg-2 stream that happens when the provider suddenly changes the codec of the elementary audio stream.

I am trying to generate this by concatenating two .ts files with ffmpeg, which have the same video codec but different audio codecs. I am ending up with a .ts with the audio channel being the same codec.
One condition is that the audio PID must remain the same during the stream, it cannot be two different channels (the stream can be interrupted though).
I need to stream this both via rtp and via a usb dvb modulator (which takes files as input)

Which is the best way to simulate this situation? Is there any tools that make it easier? Am I stuck to manually changing the file that is being streamed (interrupting the stream)?

Command output when concatenating:

```
[tomi@tomi-note2 ~]$ ffmpeg -i snippet_aac.ts -i snippet_mp2.ts -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" concat_stream.ts
ffmpeg version n4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'snippet_aac.ts':
  Duration: 00:02:00.02, start: 1.410111, bitrate: 559 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 49152 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s
Input #1, mpegts, from 'snippet_mp2.ts':
  Duration: 00:02:00.01, start: 1.422422, bitrate: 797 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #1:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 49152 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #1:1[0x101](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mpeg2video) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (mpeg2video) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (mp2) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg2video)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (mp2)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'concat_stream.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 mp2
frame= 7200 fps=2169 q=31.0 Lsize=   23681kB time=00:04:00.00 bitrate= 808.3kbits/s speed=72.3x    
video:9878kB audio:11252kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 12.074516%
```

Comment: @llogan just updated the question with the output of the concat

Comment: Try the concat protocol or concat demuxer, both with stream copy (`-c copy`), instead of the concat filter. Example: `ffmpeg -i "concat:mp2.ts|aac.ts" -c copy output.ts` Output will be a broken file.

Comment: Hmm I got an output, but like you said, a broken file. Tested streaming that with udp to vlc. Opened the stream, all good. When the codec switch is supposed to happen, audio goes mute. I reopened the stream to see if it was a vlc problem, but still no sound.

Comment: I assumed you wanted a broken file for testing purposes. By broken, I mean a file that naively switches from AAC to MP2 or MP2 to AAC.

Comment: I will have to test this with the device itself on monday. I am by no means a telecom expert, but the issue we were having was with a TV channel changing the codec for their audio channel. If I understand correctly, this would never happen with a file/continuous stream, you'd have to interrupt the stream no?

Comment: @llogan it seems that for most applications, I will have to interrupt the stream and start again with a different codec. However, for the DekTek modulator using their StreamXpress software, I can concatenate the different ts files using dd like this:
`dd if=snip_aac.ts > out.ts; dd if=snip_mp2.ts >> out.ts`

I tested the resulting file and it works, but only for DekTek's software (other programs just end at the first snippet's duration)